# How hard is stamping concrete?

Tags: concrete

I want to put a 2' border around my driveway of colored and stamped concrete.  I have gotten bids that almost $3,000.  I have called the concrete company and asked how much 5 yards of colored concrete would be and it is $650.  I really can't see spending more than $200 on the forms and release agent, and I think I can pour it myself with maybe one other person.

So, questions:

1. Can I rent the stamps?
2. How many people do you think I will need to pour and stamp 5 yards before it hardens too much?

Comment: If the border is just 2 ft wide, how long and thick is it? 5 yards is a lot of concrete.

Comment: it's not cost effective to buy premixed concrete for small jobs. I'd suggest looking at mixing your own (rent a mixer) or consider pavers for that size of a border.

Comment: it is 2 feet wide, but both sides of my 46' driveway and a small pad on the side of the house for our trashcan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, what you want to do is a three step process.  You first need to pour the concrete into the forms and screed it. The second step is to float it and bring some of the butter out. The third step is to stamp the partially dried concrete.  The stamping can go pretty quick if you had two molds set up on a tamp or step board that can be tapped with a mallet. The working time can vary, temp, humidity etc, but you usually have an hour or two to do what you need to do. Ask the concrete company to give you a longer cure mix, just a bit wetter

Comment: That's what I was wondering.  I know how to pour, screed, float etc. but I don't know if I can stamp 5-6 yards in an hour.  You can ask for a longer curing time?

Comment: Also, that is a good idea to rig up something for two or three molds together to make it faster.  THANKS!

Comment: what size stamp do you intend to use?

Comment: Well, I think they are normally about 2.5'-3'. I was just thinking about your suggestion of:  `The stamping can go pretty quick if you had two molds set up on a tamp or step board that can be tapped with a mallet.`  I can lay two or three down at the same time.  If it's only 2' wide I can be done in 30 minutes.